# OpenCV C++ How do I remove edges with low curvature?

Tags: c++, opencv, edge-detection

I am having trouble removing false (not exactly false, but ones I don't need) edges from an image.

[image: Image I want to remove edges from]

Since this is an image of a human ear I don't want to use edges caused by things other than the ear.

[image: Edges I want to remove]

This is the code in C++ that I use to show this kind of Edge image:

```
#include "opencv2\opencv.hpp"
#include "SkinSegmentator.h"
#include "AutoCannyDetector.h"


Mat referentImage, queryImage;    
loadByFilename(imageType, queryImage, IDstring);

int erosion_size = 6;
    Mat element = getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_CROSS,
        cv::Size(2 * erosion_size + 1, 2 * erosion_size + 1),
        cv::Point(erosion_size, erosion_size));
//Dilating and eroding to eliminate very small edges
dilate(queryImage, queryImage, element);
erode(queryImage, queryImage, element);
skinSegmentator.segmentSkin(queryImage, false);
equalizeHist(queryImage, queryImage);
Mat queryEdge;
GaussianBlur(queryImage, queryEdge, Size(11, 11), 3);
autoCanny.detect(queryEdge);
namedWindow("Query Edge Map", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Query Edge Map", queryEdge);
```

How can I achieve this removal for any kind of ear image? If I am not mistaken, this should be achievable if I can detect and remove edges with low curvature, but I can't find a way to do this.

Here is the original image and the Skin Segmentation:
[image: Original image]
[image: Skin Segmentation]

Comment: Could you post the original image

Comment: Compute curvature first, then filter hat you need. Similar problem here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/164349-how-to-calculate-the-curvature-of-a-boundaries-in-binary-images

Comment: I'd try to get a better segmentation, and then compute the edges only of the.interesting part

Comment: The original image and skin segmentation has been uploaded

Comment: Visually, I can't tell a valid curve fragment in the ear from an alien fragment. I doubt that any geometric criterion can do, and certainly not "low curvature".

Comment: Why not declare an ROI using Rect object